# Why is CTRL + = shortcut blocked?

Tags: terminal, shortcut

When I'm e.g. in the Terminal and press <kbd>CTRL^</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> I get the "invalid key sound". I need to bind this shortcut to a Terminal app, but it doesn't work. Just get this sound and it's not evaluated.

What's blocking it?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1527433/ctrl-shortcut-binding-in-macos-terminal

Comment: @Tetsujin and here I was thinking the number on the inbox were useful answers... Honestly, it's difficult to decide what to do in these cases, as typically whatever site is posted on, there will be someone asking to use the other one.

Comment: This is an AD question, since it is a specific macOS/Mac question

Comment: @X_841 sorry, what's AD?

Comment: AD == Ask Different == *here*. ;)

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the url and couldn't figure out how you came from Apple to AD :D thanks.

Comment: Actually I just remembered that I customized my posts for each site. I'm asking different things, and that's because I'm not sure if the problem is MacOS or emacs related. So I don't agree with this being (strictly speaking) cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `<CTRL-=>` *is* an invalid key combination in a terminal interface.

(Hint:  There's no such corresponding ASCII character.)